# Python array in a loop

Tags: python, loops, annotations

I apologize for the vague name, I don't know if there is a specific name for what I am trying to do.

I am having trouble getting my function to work. What I am trying to do is add a number to an array if it is between the variable newPoint and 0, then take that number away from newPoint until it is less than or equal to 0. However when I try to print the array out, it is empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
def setupArray():
    newPoint = 500
    array = []
    if newPoint > 0:
        x = random.randint(1, 500)
        if newPoint > x:
            array.append(x)
            newPoint = newPoint - x
    elif newPoint <= 0:
        print(array)
        return array
```

Comment: You are forgetting the loop part

Answer (score 1):

You had no loop, this should be what you are looking for:

```
import random

def setupArray():
    newPoint = 500
    array = []
    while newPoint > 0:
        x = random.randint(1, newPoint)
        array.append(x)
        newPoint = newPoint - x
    return array

print(setupArray())
```

Comment: um, that's not valid syntax according to my python interpreter:
$  python < test.py
  File "<stdin>", line 12
    print(array)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete the `elif` line, I'm updating my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but why is that that "if" wont make the loop?

Comment: `If` isn't any kind of loop, it just happend once in your code, you should use `while` or `for` to make it

Comment: You may find helpful information here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Better Ruben - good to limit the upper range of random numbers to `newPoint`.  Did you catch that @Cam ?  Firther, `x` now has to be between 1 and `newPoint` and `newPoint` is `> 0`, so you can get rid o the `if` statement; it's always true.

Comment: That correct, the `if` is never false. I updated my answer and removed it. Thanks @DanFarrell